# How to skip installation of a debian package if a file exist in the system?

Tags: packaging, source-packages

I'm interesting in avoiding the installation of the content of a debian package when a file is present in the system, eg. /usr/local/bin/token.

I'd like than the debian package will look for the token in the pre-installation phase (preinst?) and decide to install or not the content afterwards, maybe I could just delete the content to avoid copying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `preinst` script exits with an error (non-zero exit code), `dpkg` calls the `postrm` script with `abort-install` as argument, according to [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts). So you can test for the file's existence in `preinst` before anything is done, do an `exit 1`, if it exists, and do nothing in `postrm` if called with `abort-install` *and* the file exists (since the `postrm` for must be certain that the install failed due to the existence of that file).

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately if I do what you suggest me, apt-get will finish with a "Non installed" state, what I want is that it just skips copying the files if a file exist. For example I could install the package, create the token and the further package upgrades wouldn't override the initial files. I know about pinning (which could help to resolve this problem from the client side), but I'm more interested in a package-side technique

Comment: Then is not pinning the right (package-side) way? I assume you're using a private repository, in which case you know the repository details already. So all you need to do is drop a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`. This file can either part of the package or created by post/pre-inst scripts.